# Any Amazon AWS SQS gui available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Hello all I am developing a software that uses amazon simple queue service and just want to know if there is any gui available to help me easily check the status of some queues, is there any out there?

Many thanks,
Thiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you have a cloudMQ message queue service, but i never used it actually.
You may use OnlineMQ service for FREE, it has a handy GUI to define queues.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon just released an update to their AWS Management Console - it now includes an SQS management area.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/WorkingWithSQS.html

[image]